# eclipse change content on save

Tags: eclipse

i have implement a ResourceChangeListener and catch the save event. Now i want to add some code to the File. How i can do that?? I try to use BufferedReader/BufferedWriter but than the i must refresh the file. If i try it with IFile.refreshlocal() i got an error that the file is lock?

Answer (score 1):

May be the article "[How You've Changed! Responding to resource changes in the Eclipse workspace](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html)"

You need to access a resource in a workspace in a thread safe manner. (From [this post](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg68407.html))

If you are making resource changes outside of a `IWorkspaceRunnable` (old) or `WorkspaceJob` (new), that could be the cause of your "is locked" message: the workspace could be 
modified at anytime.
Placing your resource changes inside a `WorkspaceJob` ensures you will not have lock issues with other threads.
You will not need to update the resource view tree or run a `refreshLocal()`.  `WorkspaceJob`, if all goes well, will handle that for you.

See also article "[On the Job: The Eclipse Jobs API](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html)" for more on the `WorkspaceJob`.

[image]

> `[...]` our job will not run if a scheduling rule is held by another thread for the workspace root itself or for any of the resources contained in the workspace.
>   Once this job is running, no other threads will be able to obtain a rule for the above-mentioned resources until the job in our example completes.